# What to say if you want to comfort your superior who is sick?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, words, usage

Usually, some Japanese in our company say to us 気をつけてください but in that case they are the superior. Now one of our superior is sick and we want to comfort him like "please take care of yourself and get well soon". How to say it in Japanese in a polite/respectful way?

Answer (score 2):

気{き}を付{つ}けてください means "please pay attention", or "please take care of yourself",　so feel free to use it.

And when it comes to your superior, you can add お before 気, and say "お気をつけてください" to show respect.

As for "feel better soon" or "get well soon", you can say "お大事に（おだいじに）".
I think there is no problem to say it to you superior.

And please pay attention to another similar expression, which is "お元気で", because its meaning resembles お大事に, except that you cannot use it on a sick person. You use it when you finish talking to someone just to show that you hope he will keep being healthy.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [自愛]{じ・あい}.

> - ご自愛ください　→　Please take care of yourself
> - ご自愛を祈ります　→　(Same)  "I'll pray that you..."

Using 祈る with a superiour in your company might be a little too familiar, so ください is probably the better choice here.

Refer also to [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1888/78) and [this one](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/8221/how-do-you-say-please-tell-your-wife-to-get-well-soon?rq=1).